# Tag excerpts get truncated at 300 characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-excerpt

Tag excerpts can normally be as long as 460 characters, but with the current July 2018 design, we can only see the first 300 characters:

[image]

---

Truncating the excerpts makes no sense: we should either display it fully or reduce the allowed length for it.

Comment: You can see the rest by clicking at "Learn more..." button, I suppose?

Comment: Well, yeah, but at that point you see the full wiki too, so... Don't really need an *excerpt*

Comment: @user202729 It brings you to the full wiki page.

Comment: We don't need any of this anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed, no more excerpts of excerpts.

[image: Full Excerpt]